# Sort Object Containing Multiple Arrays: JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting

Emm..I have a sample example, which having Object with Arrays,

Lets Consider

```
obj = {
 code:[1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, ..etc],
 name:['John', 'Kerry', 'Stepen', 'Mery', ..etc],
 priority:[20, 40, 10, 30, ..etc] //containing more than 10000 elements in an array
}
```

Expected Output:

```
obj = {
 code:[1003, 1001, 1004, 1002, ..etc],
 name:['Stepen', 'John', 'Mery', 'Kerry', ..etc],
 priority:[10, 20, 30, 40, ..etc] //Sort on Priority basis
}
```

Could any one have simple & faster way of sorting for this kind of pattern?

Thanks & Regards
Niks

Comment: Yes..all arrays are related..& wanna sort on the basis of priority.

Comment: Too bad it's closed now. Anyway here is maybe better answer then any of the from the duplicated question: http://jsfiddle.net/da2nyohh/1/

Comment: @dfsq You can always submit that as an answer to the other question.

Comment: @nbrooks I know, but this answer targets this specific question, don't feel like rewriting it for other one. So I will just leave it here, maybe OP will see it and it will help him.